# Rspec How to replace a model with an initializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, mocking

I have a form that takes values, like `name`, `description` and a zip file that completes other values `version`, etc...

not being able to pass the zip in the parameters because too complicated, I would like to initialize directly the values in the model

Something like this `MyClassModel.new(version: Faker::Name.name)`

```rb
expect do
   post back_office_x_url, params: { x: valid_attributes }
end.to change(MyClassModel, :count).by(1)
```

how to do so that when I send my request the used class is replaced by the one I initialized ? or is there a better method ?

Comment: What do you mean by "the zip file completes the version", and "passing the zip in the parameters is too complicated"?

Comment: Your question feels like a classic example of [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): You have described a partial solution, rather than describing the true nature of the original problem.

Comment: I mean... Yeah, sure, you could temporarily save a fake version name and then asynchronously update it later with the real version name. But that sounds very hacky, convoluted, and likely leads to a different error right around the corner (due to the storage of a "temporary" fake version number).

Comment: Also, why would you want to *randomly generate* a fake version name for this hack? You might as well call it `"version-information-pending"` instead of confusing people with an unpredictable `Faker::Name.name`.

Comment: @TomLord this is for testing in RSpec the OP appears to be looking for a way to mock this information; however in doing so I think they are missing the point of the test, as this spec appears to be testing that a record is actually created.

Comment: I have to fill in some fields to register my models, some of them come from the form and the rest from the zip I open and parse the json file inside, so to avoid sending a zip file, I would like to fill in the template fields and not use the parse part

Comment: The way to do file uploads in tests is to use file fixtures. https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-9/docs/file-fixture

Comment: I think the main idea is not worse (filling in the model), because I forgot to specify but after the zip file is uploaded on S3 I could mock but that would add the fact that I have to put the zip in the project or to generate a zip with the same documents inside, maybe I've formulated the problem too badly